# Cut Row & Paste in Different Sheet based on COLUMN Value in App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here's what I need to do using App Script:

1. In the sheet "Library Materials", find a row based on Column 3's value.
2. If it is "Unpaid Fines & Refunds" select the row, if it is "Library Materials" leave it.
3. Paste that row into a the sheet of the same spreadsheet called "Unpaid Fines & Refunds".

Notes:

- In the spreadsheet "Unpaid Fines & Refunds"  row 1 is frozen and reserved for column headers.

****Thank you for your help!!**

Comment: Does it have to be cut and paste or can it be live using `=query("Library Materials"!A1:Z, "Select * where C = 'Unpaid Fines & Refunds'", 1)`

Comment: it can be any way to get those rows over to the other sheet... I just didn't know how else to explain it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the data in "Library Materials" with `getRange`. Loop through each row, and check the value of the cell in Column 3. If it's "Unpaid Fines & Refunds", use `getValues` and `appendRow` to copy and paste the row from "Library Materials" to "Unpaid Fines & Refunds". This may not be the most correct way to do it, and you'll need to double check the syntax, but this would be a good place to start:

```js
// get the spreadsheet and sheets
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var libraryMaterials = ss.getSheetByname("Library Materials");
var finesAndRefunds = ss.getSheetByName("Unpaid Fines & Refunds");

// gets the data in Library Materials
var range = libraryMaterials.getRange(1, 1, libraryMaterials.getLastRow(), libraryMaterials.getLastColumn());
var data = range.getvalues();

// loops through rows in data
for (var i = 0; i > data.length; i++) {
  var stay = "Library Materials";
  var copy = "Unpaid Fines & Refunds");
  var check = data[i][3]; // ith row, 3rd column
  if (check == stay) {continue}; // do nothing
  else if (check == copy) {
    var rowToCopy = [range[i]].getValues();
    finesAndRefunds.appendRow(rowToCopy[0]);
  }; // copy the row
  else { Logger.log("error message") }; // send an error message
}; // end i
```

If you'd like to delete the row add  the line `libraryMaterials.deleteRow(i);` into the end of the `if else`.

Comment: Thank you so much veryrad. Yes there is a syntax error line 16. Can't quit figure out why but this has helped me immensely! Thank you.

Comment: What's the line you're having trouble with? Can you update you're question with your code?